# line breaks in editors window

Tags: winedt

I'm using WinEdt 9.1 and wanna have all words in front of my eye but when I am writing the text it goes until I put Enter, it goes to next line. if I write more than 100 words in a line it wouldn't go to next line, and makes my crazy when I don't know what I've written in the previous line. 
How can I find settings of line break in editor's environment (not in exports such as .pdf)?

Comment: you are describing some editor but have not said what editor you are using, you need to make your question clearer if you want help.

Comment: Ok! thanks for your advice:)
I am using winedt9.1. Every paragraph I'm writing is staying in a very long line and I need to scroll to right and left to see the rest of my text.

Comment: I have not used that editor but if it doesn't auto-wrap why not just hit the return key every now and then? No one forces you to type the document on one line.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 7):

In WinEdt, go to Options -> Preferences, Wrapping tab and check the option "Use Fixed Right Margin"

[image]

That's it.

The value can be changed in "Fixed Right Margin" text field.